# "RangeError: Invalid typed array length" for seemingly-valid inputs

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

I have the following snippet:

```
new Uint16Array( arraybuffer, 0, 18108 );
```

I know that `arraybuffer` is an instance of [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer), and that `arraybuffer.byteLength` is 31984. The content of the arraybuffer is a black box to me. Because the buffer's byteLength is > 18108, I expect this to just work. Instead, I get the following errors:

Chrome:

> RangeError: Invalid typed array length

Firefox:

> TypeError: invalid arguments

What might cause this to fail, or how can I inspect an ArrayBuffer I can't open?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I misunderstood the TypedArray / Uint16Array constructor. The second argument is a `byteOffset`, but the third argument is *not* byte length: It is length in elements.

From [TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#Syntax) docs:

> **length**
>
> When called with a length argument, an internal array buffer is created in memory of size length multiplied by BYTES_PER_ELEMENT bytes containing 0 value.

Since `Uint16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT` is 2, the arraybuffer would need to be at least `2 * 18108` bytes long, which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error recently, so I had used ffmpeg to create wavfiles so I supposed this was the right format. Then, you can try open with Python librosa or scipy and check, my problem was ffmpeg produced wav files but mp3layer format, and I needed to transform to pcm format.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also got same problem when was trying to open 200 files and get some data from their ArrayBuffer parts. 20 files always cause error `RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 262144` so i solved it using `ArrayBuffer.slice(startByte, endByte)`
So this

```js
new Int16Array( arraybuffer, byteOffset, byteLength/2 )
```

changed to this

```js
new Int16Array( arraybuffer.slice( byteOffset, byteOffset + byteLength ) )
```

but `slice` creates new ArrayBuffer so u can't change arraybuffer by which this array was created